# Continuous use of mutt

Tags: mutt

I would like to use `mutt` continuously, allow me to explain what I mean with an example. My typical workflow is this:

- Open up `mutt`
- Compose a message
- Press `y` to confirm send action
- ... **wait!**
- Compose another message
- Press `y` to confirm send action
- ... **wait!**

I am connected to my Gmail over IMAPS.

The problem is that often I need to reply to many messages in sequence and the pattern above is obviously unacceptable because the program does not return control to me whilst it is trying to deliver the message in the background. My time is valuable and I can't be waiting for a machine to do its job after I expressed my intent (to send) to it already, can I?

---

- Can I configure `mutt` so that it does the message delivery in the background, immediately returning control to me to compose more messages?

---

My current workaround to this is running `mutt` within a `tmux` session with multiple windows, all running `tmux` and switching to another window to compose the next message as the previous is being delivered. This is a bad kind of "hack", I say.

My settings:

- smtp_url="smtps://robottinosino@smtp.googlemail.com:465/"

---

```
# Gmail configuration
set  folder            =  "imaps://imap.googlemail.com:993"
set  spoolfile         =  "imaps://imap.googlemail.com:993/[Gmail]/All Mail"
set  postponed         =  "imaps://imap.googlemail.com:993/[Gmail]/Drafts"
# set  record          =  "imaps://imap.googlemail.com/[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
set  record            =  "/home/tinosino/Sent_Messages.txt"
set  realname          =  "Tino Sino"
set  imap_user         =  "robottinosino@gmail.com"
set  imap_pass         =  ""
set  smtp_url          =  "smtps://robottinosino@smtp.googlemail.com:465/"
set  smtp_pass         =  ""
set  from              =  "robottinosino@gmail.com"
set  sort              =  threads
set  editor            =  "vim"
```

---

#### What I have tried already:

- I set `sendmail_wait = -1` but the delay in sending a message remains

Comment: The recommendation you'll probably get from mutt folks is to use a separate MTA that can do queuing, and then set `sendmail_wait` to `-1`.

Comment: How do I know which MTA is active now and could I integrate "another" MTA into my `mutt` workflow? (e.g. press reply in `mutt`, inside an IMAP folder and offload to `sendmail` perhaps?) Recommendations as to which MTA to use? Sample online .muttrc file with that MTA configured?

Comment: Using the local MTA is default in mutt, I believe. Which MTA does your system have installed? That's probably a reasonable choice, unless it is local-only.

Comment: It's also possible you are using the built-in SMTP, which is in newer versions of mutt.  `:set ?smtp_url` to check, I think.  I never figured out how to configure `exim` or `sendmail` for multiple account sending so I just use `mstmp` with the packaged `msmtpQ` script, although it's a bit lacking in functionality (in particular since it's not a daemon you have to check for and retry failed messages yourself).

Comment: Is it just using Gmail's? smtp_url="smtps://robottinosino@smtp.googlemail.com:465/"

Comment: Yes, that setting means you are using mutt's built-in SMTP support to talk directly to gmail.

Comment: Does that support background sending with automatic retries?

Comment: @jw013: setting sendmail_wait to -1 did not help, just for the record. I am still gonna keep it in my muttrc though..

Comment: @Robottinosino Of course `sendmail_wait` doesn't do anything when you are *not using `$sendmail`*.  Instead, you are using mutt's very basic *built-in* SMTP client, and I don't think that supports background send.  My comment said to "use a separate queuing MTA and *then* set `sendmail_wait`", meaning the first step is required for the second.

Comment: It is possible that the delay is not because of smtp, which is usually pretty fast. But due to saving the message into imap "Send" folder. Try run mutt in debug mode "mutt -d 5" and examine the log file after sending a few emails.

Comment: Good idea! Did not know about debug mode! Thx!

Comment: This also seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448179/offlineimap-and-mutt-with-gmails-all-mail-folder#14450289

Answer (score 6):

Generally there are three different ways of sending mail with Mutt:

- Using SMTP directly from within Mutt. This is what you are doing by specifying `smtp_url`. In this case Mutt will connect to `smtp.googlemail.com` and deliver through SMTP.
- Using a `sendmail` program which will directly deliver the mail through an SMTP connection and only return after it's done. [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/) is an example of this type of program. You can set Mutt's `sendmail_wait` variable to specify how long it will wait for `sendmail`to return before giving up and putting delivery into the background.
- Using and MTA which can do local queueing, e.g. Postfix. The `sendmail` program will usually return almost immediately when Postfix has added the mail to its local queue. You can configure Postfix to [use Gmail as an SMTP relay](http://mhawthorne.net/posts/postfix-configuring-gmail-as-relay.html), it will then forward all (non-local) mails to Gmail in the background.

Comment: A problem with the second proposal is that if `msmtp` fails, you get no notification if it's in the background. Do you know if that is fixable?